# How to force python to be only in the D:\Python27 folder?

Tags: windows, python-2.7, configuration, installation

After installation for windows 10, in D:\Python27 directory it also makes folders in C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python

How to manage PATH and other environment variables to make python use only D:\Python27 directory, avoiding of creating some new directories.

When I try to run  python PyPM under command line, it creates the C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python folder and installs packages there.

Comment: Python doesn't have any say what the OS does with registration data; see [How does the Roaming folder work?](http://superuser.com/q/312136)

Comment: @MartijnPieters, thank you for the link, but why running the PyMP creates folders inside Roaming, not just in the Python27?